# Bootstrap resize container on click to side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have two divs...

```
<div class="row">    
    <div id="general" class="col-sm-4">
        <p>General content.</p>
        <p id="show">Open extra content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="extra" class="alert alert-info col-sm-8">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>            
        <p>Here is the extra content!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The general content div should always show, and the extra content div should show when the `#show` paragraph is clicked.

As you can see, the general div is 1/3 of the page, and the extra div is 2/3 of the page (when opened).

I want the general div to fill the whole width of the page when the extra div is closed, and fill the ususal 1/3 when it is open, making it behave like this...

[image]

How would I do this with jQuery / Javascript / CSS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you will change div `#general` class, resolve it.
Firstly when `#extra` closed, `#general` set `class="col-sm-12"` and use this code;

```
    $("#general").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-sm-4');
    $("#extra").show();
});
```

and you can use again this code when div `#extra` close.

Answer (score 0):

Initially add `col-sm-12` class to your #general so that it shows fully and hide the #extra div with `hide` class. Then on the button click, with jquery swap the classes to display #extra div.

```
$("#show").on('click',function(){
  if($("#extra").hasClass('hide')){ 
      // in case its already hidden
      $("#general").removeClass('col-sm-12').addClass('col-sm-4');
      $("#extra").removeClass('hide').addClass("show");
  } else {
      // in case its already visible
      $("#general").removeClass('col-sm-4').addClass('col-sm-12');
      $("#extra").removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
  }
});
```